# white screen of death when selecting multiple options in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

No problem using the following:

```
example.com/results/?WhatDistrict%5B0%5D=Haiku
```

White screen of death (nothing at all displays) when query becomes:

```
example.com/results/?WhatDistrict%5B0%5D=Haiku&WhatDistrict%5B1%5D=Hana&WhatDistrict%5B2%5D=Kahului
```

Comment: White screens typically mean that your server (or sandbox) is configured to suppress error messages.  While in development, you should either display warnings and errors, or log them and view your logs.  You're probably throwing a fatal PHP error.  Until you get a hold of that error, nobody can help you.

Comment: There is no error, I also tried with an empty page and still not even the basic theme will load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is quite obvious when you think about it - the query string has a character limit and it was being surpassed by adding more parameters to the string.  I will try to switch everything to pass by POST.